# Is Google map geocoding limited to 2500 per day or per 24 hours?

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know if the limit touches an entire day or a period of 24 hour starting from the first request you do and until tomorrow at the same hour in the day?

Example:
I make 2500 request today from 14h00 to 19h00.

Result:
Tomorrow at 2h00AM I will be able to make more request?
OR
I have to wait until 19h00 tomorrow before I can make more request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another page where they talk about the rate and daily limit.

[Usage Limits for Google Maps API Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits?hl=fr#problems)

> Sending too many requests per day. Sending requests too fast, i.e. too
>   many requests per second. Sending requests too fast for too long or
>   otherwise abusing the web service.
>
> If you exceed the usage limits you will get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status
>   code as a response.
>
> This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses
>   and switch to returning only status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT until more
>   usage is allowed again. This can happen:
>
> Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your
>   application sent too many requests per second.
>       Some time in the next 24 hours, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per day. The time of day at
>   which the daily quota for a service is reset varies between customers
>   and for each API, and can change over time.
>
> Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your
>   application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This
>   can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request.
>   If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending
>   too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too
>   many requests per second.

On the same page there is also a video.
:-)
[Maps API for Business: Using the v3 Geocoding API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC6IFprj1AA)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#Limits), the usage limits are :

> Users of the free API: 2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
>   Maps for Business customers: 100,000 requests per 24 hour period.

We are speaking about a **24 hour period**, so in your example, if you make 2500 requests from 2PM to 7PM, you won't be able to do any request since tomorrow 7PM.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The limit is now 5000 queries per day for the free tier.